# Create 2 lists comparing each value to each other value from 1 list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hard to put into words when I'm not entirely in with the jargon. Any help is appreciated.

I need to turn this list of names:

```
abby
david
ronald
jenny
```

into this list of names comparing themselves individually:

```
abby abby
abby david
abby ronald
abby jenny
david abby
david david
david ronald
david jenny
ronald abby
ronald david
ronald ronald
ronald jenny
jenny abby
jenny david
jenny ronald
jenny jenny
```

but for about 20K rows so I can't do it manually

Comment: Does it have to be with a formula? Or is VBA an option?... i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630030/produce-all-combinations-from-a-list-of-names-in-excel

Comment: @BigBen I'd actually never touched VBA before but I got that link working. Thanks mate!